# Is fungal growth still common with modern lenses?

Tags: lens, fungus, lens-construction

I've been reading up on how to avoid fungal growth in camera lenses. I came across an article that suggested that fungal growth is uncommon in this modern time because the construction of lenses have improved over the past few decades. Just wondering if this is true?

And if fungal growth is still a common issue, how would I best avoid it in humid conditions like south-east asian countries?

Comment: Are you asking us to fact-check the article? Please link to the article.

Comment: Is proper capitalization still commonly taught in schools ?

Comment: @MichaelC It is not part of the regular education plan anymore. It was taken out together with the chapter about not having spaces in front of a question mark: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark

Comment: @jarnbjo You got me. I made one unintentional typo. I guess that's equally as egregious as not even bothering to try and capitalize the first word of each sentence  or of proper nouns and the first person singular pronoun?

Comment: Grammar issues can be resolved by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Modern is a very ambigous term.

1990s and 2000s lenses are (speaking from experience as an avid user of adapted vintage glass) certainly not less susceptible to it - and they tend to be harder or unrealistic to repair if it happens.

There are lenses notorious for easily developing fungus on certain elements (as in, many copies will have a similar pattern, and there is a high likelyhood of ANY secondhand copy having some), which appears to empirically suggest that a) there is indeed a heavy dependence on glass type, coating type, and lens barrel design (condensation lock in?) with regards to whether you will rarely get fungus, or easily get fungus that does no irreversible damage, or easily get permanent damage, b) that it is a myth that fungus spreads indiscriminately and easily to other lenses - if that were the case, you would often find lenses with fungal growth on every element, which is actually uncommon unless they were really stored in pessimal conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Fungal growth is less common in recent lenses mainly because the glue used to hold some lens groups together is no longer an organic compound made from the sap of the Canadian Balsam Pine, as it was for many years. Fungi need three things to grow:

- Moisture
- Organic material for nourishment
- Protection from UV rays

Answer (score 0):

Fungi is still a common problem in areas with a high level of humidity. Dry boxes are often used to store equipment in tropical areas.